# Longest time between goals in NHL playoffs

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl, scoring, postseason

Eric Staal of the Minnesota Wild scored a goal against the Winnipeg Jets on April 15th of the 2017/18 NHL season. The last playoffs goal he had scored came 9 years before that for the Carolina Hurricanes.

Is this the longest time between 2 playoffs goals for any player in the history of the NHL? Please provide the player with this record including the dates and the teams he scored the goals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The longest time between two consecutive NHL playoff goals for a player is **11 years**, which has been done by 5 players:

1. **Craig Ludwig**: 103 games apart, 4079 days

   1. 04/09/1988, **Montreal** @ Hartford
   2. 06/10/1999, **Dallas** vs Buffalo
2. **James Patrick**, 72 games apart, 4027 days

   1. 04/21/1990, **NY Rangers** vs Washington
   2. 04/30/2001, **Buffalo** vs Pittsburgh
3. **Bob Goldham**: 20 games apart, 4004 days

   1. 04/16/1942, **Toronto** at Detroit
   2. 04/02/1953, **Detroit** vs Boston
4. **Walt McKechnie**: 1 game apart (consecutive!), 3994 days

   1. 05/03/1968, **Minnesota North Stars** @ St. Louis
   2. 04/10/1979, **Toronto** @ Atlanta Flames
5. **Mathieu Schneider**, 35 games apart, 3962 days

   1. 06/05/1993, **Montreal** @ Los Angeles
   2. 04/10/2004, **Detroit** vs Nashville

10 years apart has been achieved by 14 players, 9 years by 12 players.

Source:
Looked up list of players who scored a goal in any year in the playoffs, copied all 9352 player-seasons to Excel, and then queried to see the longest time between consecutive seasons for a given player. Once I had the names, I looked them up to see the specifics on dates and games.

[Here is the Hockey-Reference list of players who scored a playoff goal during any season, and which seasons it was.](http://hkref.com/tiny/Dal7y) If you decide to double check me, beware that some players appear to have 20+ year gaps, because multiple players can have the same name (like Syl Apps!).

Here is a table of all 9+ year gaps:
[image]

Comment: Just to be complete, please add the resource you used to get the list of all players who scored a goal in playoffs. I've already accepted your answer

Comment: Added the link! Note that Hockey-Reference only displays 200 names at a time so you'll have to keep clicking "Next Page" to view all of them